# How to set a Laravel eloquent polymorph relation with condition for both parent and child

Tags: laravel, collections, model, comments, eloquent

I'm working on a comment system for laravel and trying to find a way to retrieve the correct results from database with eloquent.

Schema of the table is like that. Every comment has a comment status(enabled, disabled) and every comment may have child comments. Child comments have a relation to parent comments and both belong to same table. I want to retrieve all the comments with status enabled and my code for that is the following:

```
public function comments(): MorphMany
{
    return $this->morphMany(Comment::class, 'commentable')
        ->where('status', 'enabled');
}
```

The problem with the above is that in the returned Collection I get all the objects that status is enabled. Instead I don't want to include the comments that are enabled but their parent comment is disabled.

Example:

- parent comment: ❌disabled

  - child comment: ✔enabled
  - child comment: ✔enabled
- parent comment: ✔enabled

  - child comment: ✔enabled
  - child comment: ✔enabled
  - child comment: ❌disabled

In the above I only want to get a collection that include the enabled parent comment and it's two child comments that are enabled

Comment: Don't call `get()` inside a relationship declaration.

Comment: sure but doesn't solve the problem

Comment: I didn't expect it to fully solve your problem. Which is why it's just a comment and not an answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're doing could be best accomplished with a single DB query if the DB was further normalized with child comments put in a separate table from the parent comments.

That said, if that's not an option,
1st - get all the active parent comments in an array,
2nd - get all active child comments in an array.
3rd - loop through to pick out active child comments with a matching active parent comment.